# Why is Classical Logic interesting?

Tags: logic

What is interesting in Classical Logic and why is it so ?

It usually seems that intuitionistic logic is "more interesting" for its constructive property and its link to the Curry-Howard isomorphism (and especially to the simply typed $\lambda$-calculus).

I know that classical logic is more convenient to use in mathematics and have convenient properties like the excluded middle law or De Morgan laws and that in Proof Theory it enjoys nice properties (involutive negation for instance) but it seems that some (quite new) researches gave a new and interesting status for classical logic :

- It seems that some people gave a categorical interpretation for Classical Logic
- A link to the Curry-Howard Isomorphism through abstract machines seems to be currently investigated (by PL. Curien and H. Herbelin for instance).
- I don't know much about that but Classical Realizability (Krivine) seems to give a new status to Classical Logic.

Comment: "What is interesting in X and why is it so?" is far too broad for a useful MSE question and can only lead to opinion-based answers. Why don't **you** do some more work on the research topics you mention and come back to MSE if you have some specific questions about those topics?

Comment: @RobArthan Hm...Ok, maybe you're right

Comment: Arguably, classical logic is the only viable logic for the **meta-system**, namely the system that you use to reason about all formal systems including itself. The reason is that you cannot escape the circularity inherent in mathematics, where you cannot reason about provability without a background notion of classical logic. For a given system and sentence in its language, do you affirm that it is either provable or not? To do so you already need LEM. If you don't affirm this, then you can't prove a lot of things, such as compactness of propositional logic if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: So while a variety of different logics, including a plethora of modal logics, may be useful for describing various things, ultimately the logic underlying the foundational system probably has to be close to classical or at least a logic that has a classical arithmetic fragment. If however one rejects that, then one is essentially rejecting the notion of the complete collection of natural numbers, and so even the axioms of PA are questionable.